# Crome: Run content script in dynamically created iframe

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing an extension for Chrome (currently testing in Chrome 51). I need the content script to run in dynamically created iframes.
For example, if I understand correctly, [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio) creates a new iframe each time the user clicks "Run".

This is my manifest (well, parts of it, which I thought were relevant):

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_start",
        ...
    }],
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    ...
]
```

But the newly created frame still doesn't get my content script. I put a breakpoint in my content script's entry point and it isn't hit (it only hits for the main frame of the page, but not the frame which was dynamically created).

I know there are other similar questions but the Internet seems to be in agreement that `match_about_blank` is the way to go, but it doesn't work in my case.

**UPDATE**: So it turns out this wasn't the problem at all. I would have deleted the question (cause truly it's kind of embarrassing), but still there's a lesson to be learned here, since I spend A LOT of time investigating why my script isn't loaded.
In fact it WAS loaded. The breakpoint didn't hit probably because of some glitch in the map and/or source files (when I recompiled my TypeScript project and copied the files again, the breakpoint started hitting). I should have trusted the debugger window to see that my content script was loaded, instead of insisting on hitting the breakpoint...

[image]

Comment: If you use `alert(window.self === window.top);` to test, what will happen? This is just to ensure you are viewing the logs from correct console.

Comment: And Content scripts cannot be inserted in sandboxed frames.

Comment: @HaibaraAi I know, but I'm pretty sure it's not sandboxed. Or at least I don't see a sandbox attribute on it. Didn't find any code that sets that attribute either. How can I know for sure whether it's sandboxed?
This is what I see if I inspect the element: <iframe frameborder="0" id="iframeResult">...</iframe>
And as for checking it's top - if I run it from "iFrameResult" console then I obviously get false.

Comment: `document.getElementById("iframeResult").hasAttribute("sandbox")`?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Well, yes, of course :-) But unfortunately the result is false.

Comment: Is it possible to tell us your test extension or the test url?

Comment: You mean the URL I'm testing with? I wrote it in the original question - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

Comment: Update: I think there was some glitch before with the sources and that's why the breakpoint didn't hit. Now it hits and the problem is that communication with the background script doesn't work. I will continue debugging.

Comment: If you remove `"run_at": "document_start"`, it works well